# cannot find symbol - variable IOUtils in getting webpage content

Tags: java

I have this code to get the contents of a webpage

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in);
System.out.println(body);
```

But I'm getting

> cannot find symbol - variable IOUtils

I tried to add

```
import org.apache.commons.io.*;
```

But doesn't work. getting error:

> package org.apache.commons.io does not exist

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To use IOUtils, you need to `import sun.misc.IOUtils;`

or.. you could use a neat one liner like this using `java.util.Scanner`

```java
System.out.println(new Scanner(new URL("http://www.example.com").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next());
```

Comment: `sun.misc.IOUtils` does not have a `toString(InputStream)` method.

Answer (score 0):

[`IOUtils.toString(InputStream)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-) is part of [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), an external library which you likely have not added as dependency.

Moreover, the method itself is deprecated. You should prefer [`IOUtils.toString(InputStream, Charset)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-), which specifies the charset in which data from the input stream is encoded.

Since you are getting the encoding from the `URLConnection`, you should use [`IOUtils.toString(InputStream, String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-) instead:

```
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
```

Also note you should avoid wildcard imports; importing `IOUtils` will suffice:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

Note that from Java 9 onwards, the same can (and should) be accomplished without using an external library:

```
String body = new String(in.readAllBytes(), encoding);
```